# Object to JSON coversion: array vs. object

Tags: java, json, rest

I am converting a Java object into JSON. While converting I am getting  in the below format:

```
[{"":"","":"","":""}]
```

But what I need is this format:

```
{"":"","":"","":""}
```

i am using this following way to convert JSON:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); Staff obj = new Staff();
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
```

I want to use `@Consumes` in a JAX-RS services using this converted JSON. If I pass JSON without `[ ]`, its working fine but if I pass converted JSON  which is having `[ ]` then its showing bad request 400.

and this is the method

```
@POST @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Path("/post")
public String postMessage(Staff obj) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("First Name = " + obj.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last Name = " + obj.getLastName());
    return "ok";
}
```

Comment: How do you convert it?

Comment: Show us the Java/JAX-RS method you implemented that `@Consumes` this JSON.

Comment: Please do not use the comments for code or additional information that should be in your question. Please find the "edit" link if you must add useful information to your question